# Seasonal and trend decomposition using loess

Tags: r, intermittent-time-series

I have the following code for forecasting an intermittent seasonal time series with several zeroes in it. How do I assess the fit of the model on the training data? I just get the forecast with plot(foo1).

```
v1 <- c(1910,874,1920,350,160,685,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,176,0,16,826,0,66,3798,800,1274,638,192,160,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,28,0,0,276,0,0,1072,80,1776,240,80,528,3081,566,1483,112,272,120,0,0)
t1<-ts(v1,f=52)

foo1 <- stlf(t1)

foo1$mean<-pmax(foo1$mean,0)
par(mar = rep(2, 4))

plot(foo1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fitted.values(foo1)`. Here is the relevant quote from the "Value" section of `?stlf`:

> The generic accessor functions ‘fitted.values’ and ‘residuals’ extract useful features.

You can add this in-sample fit to your plot:

```
plot(foo1)
lines(fitted.values(foo1),col="red")
```

[image: forecast]

As a matter of fact, I wouldn't *assess* the fit in any way. Optimizing in-sample fits will usually lead to overfitting. Instead, use a holdout sample.